# Expand dynamic grid columns upto row max width?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Greet1ngs, everyone. I'm trying to implement a header on grid which dynamically moves columns to the next row on smaller screens. I use the following string to build it:

*grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(max-content, 230px));*

It kinda works but on some resolutions columns do not expand to the full width to the right and thus another background (from [body]) becomes visible from underneath. How can I make all columns even to the right end of the screen without mediaquery or calc (will try those if no other way)? Sorry for unprofessional explanation, I'm still new to coding. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNJQ5.jpg)

```css
@charset "utf-8";
.headergrid {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(max-content, 230px));
margin-top: -8px;
margin-left: -8px;
margin-right: -8px;}
.headergrid > div {
  background-color: #191D1F;}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:#1ba6fc;">
<div class="headergrid">
  <div class="location">
    &nbsp;<img src="clipart-map-location-11.png" alt="location" width="20" height="20" class="locicon"><span style="color:#E2E4C9">Москва, ул Хабаровская, 2. Cр-Вс с 12 до 18.</span>&emsp;&emsp;
  </div>
  <div class="element">
   <a href="tel:+7(977)8844 922"><img src="phngrn.png" width="25" height="25" alt="phone" class="phonicon">+7(977)8844-922</a>&emsp;&emsp;
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <a href="mailto:mail@zvteh.ru"><img src="hiclipart.com (11).png" width="30" height="20" alt="mail" class="mailicon"/>mail@zvteh.ru</a>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
  </div>
  <div class="element">
  </div>
  <div class="social">
 <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=79778844922"><img src="hiclipart.com.png" width="40" height="30" alt="whatsapp" class="whappicon"></a>&emsp;&emsp;
 <a href="https://vk.com/zvteh"><img src="hiclipart.com (12).png" width="30" height="30" alt="VK.com" class="vkicon"></a>&emsp;&emsp;
 <a href="https://telegram.me/zvteh"><img src="hiclipart.com (14).png" width="27" height="27" alt="Telegram" class="telecon"></a></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What have you done so far ? Can you show us your code ?

Comment: You should include your code directly in your question, see [ask]

Comment: Will do, yes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to put this grid into parent div box with header's background color. It will override main background there and all rows appear having 100% width at all resolutions.